# .NET Framework SmallMoney Max Value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Is there a .NET Framework const somewhere that will tell me SQL Servers SmallMoney Maximum value? I've tried looking but haven't seen any existing code.

Comment: That's not a .NET type so no. That's a SQL Server type that's best avoided. use `numeric` with the desired scale and precision instead

Comment: `smallmoney` and `money` don't store the currency so it's no better than a `numeric(19,4)` or a `numeric(10,4)`. A `smallmoney` saves *1* byte compared to `numeric(10,4)` but doesn't have the full range, `-99999.9999` to `999999.9999`

Comment: It is just stored as a 32 bit signed integer behind the scenes so you could use `Int32.MinValue/10000m` and `Int32.MaxValue/10000m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't make sense for SQL Server-specific to be build into the .NET Framework itself, which is provider-agnostic. If something like that exists, it's most likely in a library like [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient). But it's arguably not that beneficial to couple your code to the client library just to represent a constant which, by definition, will never change. I recommend getting the value from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and putting it in a constant in your own code.